# Spring Security HeaderPreAuthentication Principal Not Resolved from @AuthenticationPrincipal

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, pre-authentication

I have an existing Spring Boot Application with authentication to the web application handled by a third party authentication service. Like SiteMinder, the 3rd party service injects a header into the HTTP requests, say USER_HEADER. I am tasked with configuring the existing app to extract this HTTP header and make the resulting Auth object available to the MVC layer's controllers via the Spring Security `@AuthenticatedPrincipal` annotation.

As mentioned, project is a Spring Boot application, version 1.1.9.RELEASE, with Java 8.

(The code shown below is from a test project that mirrors functionality)

Note that **this application is Java Config only. No XML is permitted (mandate from my lead)**

By digging through the [Spring Security reference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/reference/htmlsingle/#preauth-sample) and various other articles I know that I need to use a `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter` and inject it into the filter chain to grab the username from the request header.

Filter:

```
public class HeaderAuthenticationFilter extends RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HeaderAuthenticationFilter.class);
    private final String HEADER = "USER_HEADER";

    public HeaderAuthenticationFilter() {
        super();
        this.setPrincipalRequestHeader(HEADER);

        // This setting returns an HTTP 404 with no error message instead of an HTTP 500 with the "missing header" exception message
        this.setExceptionIfHeaderMissing(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        logger.debug("Authorizing URI: " + request.getRequestURI());

        try {
            return super.getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(request);
        } catch(PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error("Could not find request header " + HEADER + " in request", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Very basic filter as you can see.

With the code I have now, the user gets extracted from the HTTP request, makes it through the PreAuthentication process where the PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken gets created by a custom AuthenticationManager, the User business object is injected into the token as the principal, and the token is finally assigned to the SecurityContext with:
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(principal);

However when I annotate my Controller methods with `@AuthenticationPrincipal User user`, the User object returned is a null'd User object. When I change the method parameter to `Authentication user` and explicitly call `user.getPrincipal()` I get the user object just fine. Is there a reason why @AuthenticationPrincipal is failing like this?

Thanks and please let me know if more details are needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `@AuthenticationPrincipal` was not resolving is because I did not annotate my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class with `@EnableWebMvcSecurity`

Adding this annotation solved the issue